# Using two ATR lengths and multipliers in an indicator for signals

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm using the UT Bot alerts indicator on Pinescript to modify the existing code to duplicate the same code to use two ATR lengths and multipliers for Long and Short. I still don't understand why it isn't working. Appreciate help from the community.

Here's my code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="UT Bot Alerts - UJ", overlay = true)

// Inputs Long
a = input(2,     title = "Long Key Vaule. 'This changes the sensitivity'")
c = input(300,    title = "Long ATR Period")

// Inputs Short
d = input(2,     title = "Short Key Vaule. 'This changes the sensitivity'")
f = input(1,    title = "Short ATR Period")

h = input(false, title = "Signals from Heikin Ashi Candles")

src = h ? security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close, lookahead = false) : close
ema   = ema(src,1)

// Long Conditions
L_ATR  = atr(c)
L_Loss = a * L_ATR


// Short Conditions
S_ATR  = atr(f)
S_Loss = d * S_ATR


ATRTrailingStop = 0.0
ATRTrailingStop := iff(src > nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max((ATRTrailingStop[1]), src - L_Loss),
   iff(src < nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(ATRTrailingStop[1]), src + S_Loss), 
   iff(src > nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - S_Loss, src + S_Loss)))


//Plot Logic
pos = 0   
pos :=  iff(src[1] < nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
   iff(src[1] > nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(ATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
   
color = pos == -1 ? color.red: pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue 

above = crossover(ema, ATRTrailingStop)
below = crossover(ATRTrailingStop, ema)


buy  = src > ATRTrailingStop and above 
sell = src < ATRTrailingStop and below

barbuy  = src > ATRTrailingStop 
barsell = src < ATRTrailingStop 

plotshape(buy,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= color.red,   textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

barcolor(barbuy  ? color.green : na)
barcolor(barsell ? color.red   : na)

alertcondition(buy,  "UT Long",  "UT Long")
alertcondition(sell, "UT Short", "UT Short")
```